# Facebook open graph image is not displayed on the first share, even though width and height are defined

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

During the last couple of weeks the window showing a shared page (before submitting the share) does not show the specified og:image on the first time the page is shared. The image is displayed on the shared post itself and on following share requests.

We ran our pages through the FB debugger and we got the following message

> The provided 'og:image' properties are not yet available because new
>   images are processed asynchronously. To ensure shares of new URLs
>   include an image, specify the dimensions using 'og:image:width' and
>   'og:image:height' tags. Learn More

The problem is we do have the og:image:width and og:image:height tags defined and the FB debugger even shows them on the same page showing this message... See attached image below.

Any idea what may be causing this?

[image: FB debugger screenshot]

Comment: lots of people are having this issue including myself. i now suspect that fb has broken their already-fragile og scraping system.

Comment: Here's a bug on official facebook tracker that looks exactly like the bug described in the question: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/184653232016624/  My page with sharing also broke down even though I haven't made any changes for months.

Comment: 10x for the notice about the fb bug!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a facebook bug as Alexey mentioned above.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/184653232016624/

However, one work around appears to be to initiate a prefetch via their api.

```
curl -X POST \
-F "id=http://your.url/here" \
-F "scrape=true" \
"https://graph.facebook.com"
```